# Load balancing between peers with DNS and javascript

Tags: javascript, caching, dns

Let's do a thought experiment (clearly, this is not a real case scenario). Say that:

- I have a huge swarm of servers. By huge I mean: millions of nodes.
- Each node is unreliable: it can (and will) go offline often, with uptimes that could be as low as 10% to 20%, much alike a peer to peer network where nodes continuously go up and down.
- Each node is weak (it has quite limited bandwidth and resources).
- Each server is publicly accessible (so don't worry about NAT translators and so on).
- Each server exposes a WebSocket interface, capable of offering (through some protocol) a set of static resources (say, images, videos and so on).

Now, say that I want to use this swarm to keep online (the static part of) a very popular website (millions and millions of users). What I do is as follows:

- I embed a javascript code in each page to connect to a bunch of servers in my network (say, 16?).
- The user successfully connects to a subset of those some peers, selects the fastest ones, loads the resources via WebSocket, then displays them.
- (Let's not care about security for now.)
- A very tight timeout mechanism allows to fallback on a standard web server if it is impossible to connect to any client in a reasonable time.

I made an actual experiment with a network of a dozen of peers, and worked smoothly. If the peers are close to my current location, loading resources from peers is actually faster than loading from my server. So good.

Now, I would like to think how can I do load balancing among all these servers with DNS. Of course, relying on round robin DNS will be a suicide: I definitely can't have a single domain with millions of A records in it.

So here is my idea, and I wonder if in principle this could work.

- I run my own DNS server, say with NodeJS and dnsd.
- Every time my DNS is asked for a subdomain like something.mywebsite.com, it returns the IP of a random, currently online server.
- To connect to the servers, the script on my webpage just randomizes subdomains.
- I can use some client side mechanism to cache the last subdomains used so that I can make use of the cached DNS records and avoid having to get my DNS server flooded when not strictly necessary.

In my mind this should work, but I could see some problems. The first that comes to my mind is: will caching DNS servers get angry at me? Say: Google's 4.4.4.4 will receive millions of requests to millions of distinct random subdomains of my domain. Will it eventually block it or stop responding or something?

Are there potentially other problems in doing this? Are there better ways of doing this? Is this completely unfeasible even from a theoretical standpoint?

Comment: At first pass, I think you just described how CDN networks work! ;)

Comment: Awesome :D It is always good news when you are discovering the wheel again. You lost some time but at least you know that it works!

Comment: To be honest it was a lazy saturday afternoon skim through (it is saturday right?!) So I may have missed a pertinent point or two, but cdn networks do manipulate DNS records in a similar way to get content that is closest to you.

Comment: @MichaelB Let me sum this up as much as possible: the con of my method is that I am using my own authoritative DNS to point random subdomains to random servers every time a new user loads resources. That is millions and millions and millions of subdomains for my domain. Is this acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core concept behind DNS is that for every addressable IP Address you have, you have a corresponding A record. This stands to logic, as every server can only have a single hostname, and DNS is about hostnames.

However, sometimes you don't want the hostname to be the name that people connect to, so instead you would use a CNAME which is the Canonical name (in this case, canonical as in authorative) for the Alias (obviously calling those an Alias might be confused with A records)

So if you are looking at Example.com you might have

```
fred  IN  A 192.168.0.1
alice IN  A 192.168.0.2 
bob   IN  A 192.168.0.3
www   IN  CNAME bob.example.com
web   IN  CNAME www.example.com
```

So unless you are actually deploying millions of servers with unique IP Addresses (if this is the case, I am very curious where you got them from and who you are!) If however you have x number of hosts and you want to provide host names for them to be connected to on the fly, then you actually want to be configuring CNAME records.

One of the interesting parts about CNAME records is that you can set up multiple redirects with them so you can layer a hierarchy with them, which you couldn't do with A records.

If you are following the [rules of DNS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035) there is no reason that google et al should have any problem with however many names you use.

An excellent place to start understanding the complexities of DNS is the [Dragonfly book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596100575.do)

**Edited to add**

If these are machines on the internet then it is perfectly acceptable to give each an A record / hostname (I'm presuming this is what you mean by subdomain)

There is no reason that you couldn't then give each A record a CNAME record.

From the perspective of DNS I see no reason that you couldn't provide load balancing in this way. You would perhaps want a test prior to sending the CNAME record to ensure that the endpoint is online. But the concept of using CNAME records to load balance certainly isn't a new one. i.e. CDNs

Comment: First of all, as I said this is pure fiction. I don't have a million servers :D Second, servers will all have different IPs. You can depict them as a population of volunteers with their laptops, if you want, just like a peer to peer network of people.

Comment: Now, if I understand well, what you suggest is that I should assign some subdomain to each and every of my servers (that is, some million a record) and make it point to the IP address of the server. Then, I could use CNAME records to make "aliases". Am I right?

Comment: If I understood everything correctly, could you please address explicitly my idea of using random subdomains to connect to random servers? The idea is: 1) javascript randomizes a subdomain (say "cjhkdjsfh.mywebsite.com"). 2) It connects to that domain. 3) My authorative DNS will return a CNAME to the subdomain of a random peer.

Comment: This is how I thought I could do load balancing, but this means that every time a new user opens my webpage, a new CNAME record for a random subdomain gets generated. Is this going to be acceptable?